# How to exclude PaperTrail versions from views in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

I'm using RailsAdmin v0.6.8 with PaperTrail for versioning.

The list, show, create and edit views for each of my has_paper_trail Models includes the versions attribute. In fact the create and edit views allow the addition/removal of versions, which doesn't really make sense to me. Other than using exclude_fields :versions for each view on each Model, is there a global way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### Method 1

If all models are inherited an abstract class(for example: "ApplicationRecord")
you can create a new file(for example: `app/models/concerns/exclude_versions.rb`):

```rb
module ExcludeVersions
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rails_admin do
      configure :versions do
        hide
      end
    end
  end

end
```

and edit the abstract class like:

```rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  has_paper_trail

  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.include(ExcludeVersions)
    super
  end
end
```

---

#### Method 2

If all models are not inherited an abstract class, you can just add such code in `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```rb
  Rails.application.eager_load! if Rails.env.development?

  ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |imodel|
    ### next if ['ApplicationRecord'].include?(imodel.name) ### if all models are inherited an abstract class, please uncomment this line, or some strange error will happen
    config.model "#{imodel.name}" do
      configure :versions do
        hide
      end
    end
  end
```

Reference: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Models#configuring-models-all-at-once

Comment: Method1 working but somehow I don't know method 2 should work but it doesn't @Mr. Mi

Comment: I try method 2 again now and it works. The code should add at the end of config. both method should restart rails server. @UmutADALI

Answer (score 0):

In your rails_admin configuratoin you can specify it:

```
config.actions do
  history_index do
    except %w(ModelA ModelB)
  end
end
```

or the other way round:

```
config.actions do
  history_index do
    only %w(ModelA ModelB)
  end
end
```

Comment: history_index maps to https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/history_index.rb. This is a separate action to allow viewing changes made to an object. I'm talking about on the list, show, create and edit pages for an object being able to hide the :versions attribute.

Comment: I too am facing this issue. The 'versions' "object" shows on the edit screen. I want to exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in the rails_admin initializer and it worked.

```
config.model 'DcDiscipline' do
  edit do
    exclude_fields :versions 
  end     
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to add this for each model. I'm looking for a global way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the global part of the question.